# cl$(B\backslash A) \subset$ int(B)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A, B$ two open subspaces such that $X=A \cup B$. I want to know if it's true that cl$(B\backslash A) \subset$ int$(B)$ or if there'a a counterexample. I tried to prove it by using a Venn diagram and it works but I didn't use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are open.

Comment: wikipedia says "A subspace is called an open subspace if the injection is an open map. Likewise it is called a closed subspace if the injection is a closed map."

Comment: What happens if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: Also note that $\operatorname{int}(B)=B,$ as $B$ is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X=A\cup B$, we have $B\setminus A=X\setminus A$; since $A$ is open, $B\setminus A$ is closed, hence $\operatorname{cl}(B\setminus A)=B\setminus A$.
On the other hand, since $B$ is open, $\operatorname{int}(B)=B$.
Thus your claim is equivalent to $B\setminus A\subseteq B$ which is true.

Without the assumption on $A$ being open the assertion is false: by taking $A=X\setminus B$, we have $B\setminus A=B$ and $\operatorname{cl}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{int}(B)$ is satisfied only for clopen subsets of $X$.

Comment: Why can we take $A=X \backslash B$? What if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint?

Comment: @Twink he means that to describe a hint for a concrete example: e.g. take $X=\Bbb R$ (connected, so no nontrivial clopens) , $A=[0,1]$, (not open!), $B=\Bbb R \setminus [0,1]$ (open) and $A \cup B= X$ but $B \setminus A = B$ and the closure of $B$ is not a subset of the interior of $B$ (as $B$ is not clopen). So your statement can fail if $A$ is not open. You can have a worse example if we take $A=\Bbb Q$ and $B$ the irrationals, say.